# How to write a switch statement shorter in JS, while also using express and Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

So the situation is as fallow:

I need to search in 3 different db for a id of a shift. 
But the shift has also a type: Activity, Food And Beverages or other.

The way i do it, in my req.body I also have a type.

So i use a switch statement to determine which db i need to search through

```js
switch(type_shift){
     case("activity"):
     response = await ActivityShiftDB.findByIdAndUpdate(id_shift, {$pull : {"support": user}}).exec();
     break;

     case("fandb"):
     response = await FoodBeveragesShiftDB.findByIdAndUpdate(id_shift, {$pull : {"support": user}}).exec();
     break;

     case("other"):
     response = await OtherShiftDB.findByIdAndUpdate(id_shift, {$pull : {"support": user}}).exec();
     break;
   }
```

This code doesn't feel DRY, 
Is there an other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the shared part after the `switch` statement:

```
let shiftDB;
switch (type_shift) {
    case "activity":
        shiftDB = ActivityShiftDB;
        break;
    case "fandb":
        shiftDB = FoodBeveragesShiftDB;
        break;
    case "other":
        shiftDB = OtherShiftDB;
        break;
    default:
        throw new Error("unknown type_shift");
}
response = await shiftDB.findByIdAndUpdate(id_shift, {$pull : {"support": user}}).exec();
```

Then, simplify by not using a `switch` statement:

```
const shiftDBsByType = {
    "activity": ActivityShiftDB,
    "fandb": FoodBeveragesShiftDB,
    "other": OtherShiftDB,
}
if (!(type_shift in shiftDBsByType)) {
    throw new Error("unknown type_shift");
}
response = await shiftDBsByType[type_shift].findByIdAndUpdate(id_shift, {$pull : {"support": user}}).exec();
```